# How to find columns of the partition of a master table in postgresql 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

In postgresql I have created a master table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_master(
column_1 text NOT NULL,
column_2 text NOT NULL,
column_3 text NOT NULL
);
```

and a partition table based on columns: column_1, column_2

```
CREATE TABLE table_col1_col2 (
CONSTRAINT table_col1_col2_pk PRIMARY KEY (column_1, column_2),
CHECK ( column_1 = 'value_1' AND column_2 = 'value_2')
) INHERITS (table_master);
```

Is there any select query in order to get the columns of the partition (column_1, column_2)?

**UPDATE**

In case I know a child table, I may use the below query:

```
WITH table_id AS (
SELECT oid 
FROM pg_class
WHERE relname = 'child_table_name'
),
con AS (
SELECT c.conname,
c.contype,
c.conkey,
c.consrc
FROM pg_constraint c INNER JOIN table_id ON c.conrelid = table_id.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'c'
)
SELECT a.attnum,
a.attname
FROM pg_attribute a INNER JOIN table_id ON a.attrelid = table_id.oid
INNER JOIN con s ON a.attnum = ANY(conkey)
```

**FINAL QUERY**

```
WITH table_id AS (
SELECT pg_class.oid 
FROM pg_class INNER JOIN pg_inherits ON pg_class.relname::text = pg_inherits.inhrelid::regclass::text
WHERE pg_inherits.inhparent = 'master_table'::regclass
),
con AS (
SELECT c.conname,
c.contype,
c.conkey,
c.consrc
FROM pg_constraint c INNER JOIN table_id ON c.conrelid = table_id.oid
WHERE c.contype = 'c'
)
SELECT a.attnum,
a.attname
FROM pg_attribute a INNER JOIN table_id ON a.attrelid = table_id.oid
INNER JOIN con s ON a.attnum = ANY(conkey)
```

Comment: You can select from master table with condition for your check statment from child table Where column_1 = 'value_1' AND column_2 = 'value_2' . It will return only records from child table

Comment: Unrelated, but: with Postgres 10 you should rather use [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE)

Comment: you can only get the SQL expression for the check constraint, which you would need to parse and extract the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can get columns of primary key.

> This returns the names and data types of all columns of the primary
>   key for the `tablename` table:
>
> ```
> SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
> FROM   pg_index i
> JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
>                      AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
> WHERE  i.indrelid = 'tablename'::regclass
> AND    i.indisprimary;
> ```

[(source)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns)

Here used the fact that primary key's uniqueness is handled by `Postgres` via index, so you can use `pg_index` table.